# Python PANDAS: How to Reverse One-Hot Encoding Back to Categorical

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with the following general layout:

```
id,ind_1,ind_2_ind_3
1,0,1,0
1,1,0,0
2,0,1,0
2,0,0,1
3,0,0,1
3,1,0,0
```

I would like to add an additional column whose values are the original indicator names when they are '1' which should look like this:

```
id,ind_1,ind_2,ind_3,ind_all
1,0,1,0,ind_2
1,1,0,0,ind_1
2,0,1,0,ind_2
2,0,0,1,ind_3
3,0,0,1,ind_3
3,1,0,0,ind_1
```

Any tips welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need

```
df['ind_all'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:] == 1).idxmax(1)


    id  ind_1   ind_2   ind_3   ind_all
0   1   0       1       0       ind_2
1   1   1       0       0       ind_1
2   2   0       1       0       ind_2
3   2   0       0       1       ind_3
4   3   0       0       1       ind_3
5   3   1       0       0       ind_1
```

Comment: What is the point of ==1 if we use idxmax? `df.set_index('id').idxmax(1).values` I think is more readable for instance.