# Matching value in a list to index where a condition is true

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a set of columns that are either 1 or 0 depending on if a condition is true. Each row will have only a single column that is one.

I'm trying to add a new column to the df that finds the column number where the value equals 1 `(e.g., column 0, 1, 2, etc.)` and return the corresponding indexed value in a list that has the same number of column elements as the dataframe.

For example, if the value is `1` in the second column for row `1`, I would want the newly added column to read `b` using the list below as a reference.

```
prim_cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

What is the best python functions to use for this? I've tried np.where, list comprehension, and a few others, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to reverse an 1-hot encoding. This answer here might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372640/python-pandas-how-to-reverse-one-hot-encoding-back-to-categorical

Comment: @kosnik: Which answer? :d

Comment: @kosnik Yes this is perfect, thank you!